# AngularJS, Jquery, required error, input using Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have angularjs with required atribute

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.bdatetime.$invalid}">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="bdatetime" value="" name="bdatetime" id="datetimepicker" required/>
        <span ng-show="myForm.bdatetime.$error.required" class="help-inline">Required</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have Jquery which place some value after processing in jquery (JQuery Third party Plugin), most simplified example below

```
$(document).on("click","#datetimepicker", function() {
    $("#datetimepicker").val("aa");
});
```

Now once I click in input box, value is auto entered using jquery without pressing any keyboard key(on just mouse click)

But Angularjs required attribute is not clear "required error" until I input some value in in input box using keyboard.

How can I bind this on click without involving keyboard input.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be,
Move following within ng controller and change input model and use *$scope.$apply*

```
$(document).on("focusout","#datetimepicker", function() {
                        $scope.bdatetime = $("#datetimepicker").val();                            
                            $scope.$apply();
             });
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse-me, but the traditional format is to create a directive.

A directive could to join the DOM events with angular data.

Please, look articles like this:

http://www.abequar.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs/